# How to validate form without refreshing the page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a login button at my Site Master. If the button is clicked, the login form will 'pop out' from the left side of screen via this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#logpad").click(function () {
    $('.menu').animate({
        left: '100%'
    }, 600);
});
```

So basically the login window is always there in the homepage, but hidden until the login button is clicked and jquery forces it out by animating it left 100% (full width).

Forgive me for the confusing names but in this case logpad represents the login button and class 'menu' represents the transparent login window that looks like this:  [image: Click here to see the image]

The problem is that whenever the incorrect email/password is given (credentials not found in my database), the page refreshes and you have to click login button again to see the same window but with an extra label "You have entered wrong email or password", from this c# code (a part of validation function):

```
 if (i > 0)
                {
                    Turists turist = TuristsFacade.TuristsGetByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    if (turist.ID != -1)
                    {
                        Session["TuristName"] = turist.Name + " " + turist.SurName;
                        Response.Redirect("~/EN/index.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = "Your email or password is incorrect.";
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        msg.Visible = true;
                    }
                    ds.Clear();
                }
```

How can I validate the form without the need to refresh page (in other words, is it possible to validate directly or another option is to make the transparent window stay in case the incorrect credentials are given).

Comment: you can use ajax in jquery for this and set login button type = button and your method return type json return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UpdatePanel which is analog to ajax calls, but in C# style. 
[Details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_ajax_control.htm)

By using this, you can update a Label, let`s stay, in which you display an appropiate message, without refreshing the page

Comment: To clarify, this is not in "C# style" but rather systemic of WebForms.  Please consider updating your answer to be more accurate.  In addition, please consider adding a small example that demonstrates how to use an Update Panel appropriately.